# tablesorterPager is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to implement [tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter) with the pager function. I imported all the js files provided on the tablesorter website. Here I have my 'head' section of my Html file:

```
<head>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script  src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" integrity="sha512-qzgd5cYSZcosqpzpn7zF2ZId8f/8CHmFKZ8j7mU4OUXTNRd5g+ZHBPsgKEwoqxCtdQvExE5LprwwPAgoicguNg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
  $("#myTable")
  .tablesorter({
    theme : "bootstrap",
    sortList: [[0, 0]]
  
    },
    widthFixed: true
  })
  .tablesorterPager({
    size: 2,
    container: $("#myContainer")
  });
});
    </script>
</head>
```

With the following table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="myTable">
                     <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">№</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th> 
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        ...
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                          <th colspan="3" class="ts-pager" id="myContainer">
                            ...                       
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                </table>
```

However, I get this error:

```
$(...).tablesorter(...).tablesorterPager is not a function
```

What's wrong? I do everything like in the demo section and in youtube tutorials but this error appears and can't realize why.

Comment: Just move the script tags from the head to the bottom of your HTML.

Comment: tablesorter is being loaded in 3x, and load the pager _after_ tablesorter.

Comment: Mottie, thanks it works fine)

Comment: I get the same issue. See here:
* Live version has changed a little.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469002/uncaught-typeerror-tablesorter-is-not-a-function-after-wp-migrate