# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function after WP migrate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

For some unknown reason, using the [table sorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter) js script to sort the table doesn't work and throws this error.

```
jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (lbrynomics.com/:2), <anonymous>:5:20)
    at e (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
```

It used to work before the WordPress jQuery update, but now it doesn't, even if I use the migrate helper.

I've tried all the other solutions found on Stack Overflow, such as making sure the page is loaded, before running the script, but nothing works.

One of the solutions, was to make sure only one version of jQuery was running. I tried that too, by disabling all plugins, but that didn't help.

I've tried swapping `$` for `jQuery` and various other options, but nothing seems to work.

The only thing I can think of, is some of my other js code isn't compatible, and is creating an issue, but I can't see where that would be. Nothing is flagged in the console.

I've added my code below, but it's not working as a snippet, probably because my CORS settings, but you can see it working and not working here:

[LBRYnomics.com](https://lbrynomics.com/)

[LBRYnomics JavaScript](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://lbrynomics.com/lbrynomics.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
// Table Sorter
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $("#sub-stats").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            1: { lockedOrder: "asc" },
      '.rank-header'   : { sorter: false }    
        }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://lbrynomics.com/lbrynomics.js?ver=2.0.83" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" defer></script>
<html>
<body>
<table class="tablesorter sticky-header" id="sub-stats">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-1">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-2">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-3">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-4">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-5">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-6">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-7">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-8">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-9">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-10">
        <col span="1" class="all-columns lnt-column-11">
    </colgroup>
<thead class="table-header">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="8" class="over-7-empty"></th>
    <th href="#notice" title="Click for more info" colspan="4" class="sorter-false over-7-fill"><span style="z-index:99999;">Change Over 7 Days</span><span style="display:none;"> </span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ln-table-header ln-sticky">
    <th title="Rank For The Current Sorted Column" class="rank-header"><p class="table-headers">Rank</p></th>
    <td title="LBRY Channel Name" title="Search Odysee Channels" class="csearch"><input type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search..." id="LNSearch" /></td>
    <th title="Tips + Supports Currently Staked"><p class="table-headers">Value</p></th>
    <th title="Total LBRY Channel Followers"><p class="table-headers">Follows</p></th>  
    <th title="Total LBRY Channel Content Views"><p class="table-headers">Views</p></th>
    <th title="Total Amount of Content Reposts"><p class="table-headers">Reposts</p></th>   
    <th title="Total Odysee likes"><p class="table-headers">Likes</p></th>
    <th title="Total Odysee dislikes"><p class="table-headers">Dislikes</p></th>     
    <th class="stats-change" title="Channel Follower Change Over 7 Days"><p class="table-headers">Follows</p></th>
    <th class="stats-change" title="Channel Content Views Change Over 7 Days"><p class="table-headers">Views</p></th>
    <th class="stats-change" title="Repost Change Over 7 Days"><p class="table-headers">Reposts</p></th>   
    <th class="stats-change" title="Rank Change Over 7 Days"><p class="table-headers">Rank</p></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
      
      
      </tbody> 
</table>
<div id="readabiltyMode"></div>
<div id="darkModeWidgets"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure there isn't another version of jQuery being loaded further down page from the scripts shown. It will wipe out plugins associated with the first version

Comment: How are you loading these scriptes - are you using the WordPress queue (doesn't look like it)? Which file contains the tablesorter initialization code. I'm guessing it's lbrynomics.js

Comment: I'm loading them in the Divi theme integration script area.

Comment: I'm not loading any versions of jQuery. I'm just using the default WP version.

Comment: I don't care for the Divi scripts tools, but, if you do use them, you DO still need to deal with WordPress jquery no conflicts mode - like `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` I'd also consider turning off Cloudflare Rocket Loader. If you were using the WP scripts queue you could ensure that a Tablesorter initialization script/file followed the tablesorter js, but making the former was dependent on the latter, and both on jQuery.

Comment: I've tried putting the script in different locations, not just there. The thing to remember. It worked before WP migrated to the newer version of jQuery. If you read my post, you can see I've already using the `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`. I have also tried turning off Rocket Loader.

Comment: Only the  external script is loaded in, via the Divi script area.
The `$("#sub-stats").tablesorter({` call, is inline, on the page. It seems to be that part that's not working.

Comment: I'm wondering if that other inline "Search" script is working. Either way, I'd consider trying things the vanilla WordPress way: IOW in a functions.php file or similar, as described in #3 here https://divi.space/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-and-jquery-to-divi/ - while making sure that the tablesorter initialization file, when enqueued, listed jquery and the tablesorter main file as dependencies, and that the code itself is properly written for WordPress no-conflicts.